# Count number of records in a field from another table in access

Tags: function, ms-access, count

I have one table that I want to keep a running count of the total records for statistical analysis in another table. I tried using a calculated field but when I type in the count function it says it isn't valid and I am really confused why.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How often this count needs to be accounted for? Once a day? Why could this not be a part of an Unbound control on a Form?

Comment: I need it to keep a constant count on one field in a table. Anytime it changes, the count needs to be updated automatically.

Comment: Count is a function, and Calculated fields are only Field dependent. They cannot be updated dynamically or if the column looking up on it will be modified. so the reason why many developed hate this concept of calculated fields to an extent. Depending on how efficiently you want the system to run, you can use Data Macros (After Insert) of the Table, to update the count value.